# PHP overload when there are a lot of request

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, server, php-8.1

I have a website that receives a lot of traffic load, and when php is not able to handle all requests the web starts to slow down, even at certain times causes an error 502 nginx, I have this setting in the php file, I have been modifying but I can not find the problem. the server has 30 gb of ram and 8 cpus, running the htop command I do not see that the server is saturated.

some one can help me to fixit.

Regards

logs

```
[02-Nov-2023 13:53:15] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 8 idle, and 94 total children
[02-Nov-2023 13:53:16] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 5 idle, and 96 total children
[02-Nov-2023 13:53:17] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (100), consider raising it
[02-Nov-2023 13:54:43] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (100), consider raising it
[02-Nov-2023 13:55:31] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (100), consider raising it
[02-Nov-2023 14:01:13] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (100), consider raising it
[02-Nov-2023 14:02:33] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (100), consider raising it
```

Comment: Have you identified any particular PHP scripts which are slow to execute perhaps, or use a lot of resources? Find the bottleneck and optimise it.

Comment: What caching, if any, have you implemented?

Comment: Your question is too general and we don't have any details about your site and running scripts, however you can check your resources (downloadable files like CSS files or images), you also should try caching and avoid reading data from your database repeatedly, if you are using any specific CMS you may be able to do caching with some plugins. If you wrote the codes yourself you should make sure they are optimized. Give more details so we can help you more

Comment: Have you tried, what the message suggests, Increasing pm.max_children?

Comment: Hello, I have not been able to detect why this slowdown occurs, currently I use redis as cache or I can even configure the local cache of the server but I do not get improvement.
It is true that many queries are made to the database but I do not know if it is a reason for the slowdown.

This is my configuration.pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers =35
;pm.max_spawn_rate = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s;
pm.max_requests = 500

Comment: If you think the server has enough CPU and RAM, what's your concern with allowing more than 100 concurrent scripts?

Comment: What is the average response time observed for each request on the browser/inspect for the script endpoints? If you can also give us some idea of what you mean by high traffic would be useful (1k concurrent users? 5k users?). Note that it's quite easy to keep busy 100 scripts on pages that are slow/do too many queries/connect many services. As others suggested: If you have room, start by raising the limit.

Comment: hi the website is https://freefy.app , actually we have about 40k users , no all are active but in some hours we can have 2-3k users at time and is when the website start to load slow , the logs tell me that the mayority request are GET because the users search songs , the database is external bu we have good conexion and latence betwen servers.
I check some blogs and some people says that the problem is with php configuration , but im not expert in php, if some one need some log or configuration i can attach.